# Adding Done/Next to numberPad

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have read the post on how to create these buttons but they use a tag system to identify the textFields.  I am using a prototype cell to create my textFields

```
func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(_ hasNextBtn: Bool = false) -> UIView {
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 163, width: 106, height: 53))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done",
                                                style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done,
                                                target: self,
                                                action: #selector(doneAction))
    let next: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next",
                                                style: .plain,
                                                target: self,
                                                action: #selector(nextAction))

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(flexSpace)
    if hasNextBtn {
        items.append(next)
    } else {
        items.append(done)
    }

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    return doneToolbar
}

@objc func doneAction() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func nextAction(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 2)

    // if textField.returnKeyType == .next {
    if textField.inputAccessoryView == next as! UIView? {
        guard let table = tableView, let ip = indexPath,
            let cell = table.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: ip.row + 1, section: ip.section)) as? FormFieldTableViewCell
            else { return true }

        return cell.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I have read this document but it does not explain how to go from textField to the next.   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UIKitCatalog_DefaultToolbarViewController_swift.html

Comment: I would really like to know the best practice for creating the nextAction function since it is not tied to a bunch of textFields but to one prototype cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Change button Type on Keyboard as follows,
// Assign in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
yourTextField.returnKeyType = .Next 
txtField.returnKeyType = .Done
txtField.returnKeyType = .Go
```

And Many more from below,

```
case Default
case Go
case Google
case Join
case Next
case Route
case Search
case Send
case Yahoo
case Done
case EmergencyCall
```

You can after handle action as desire in UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: Dev_Tandel thank you but this is not what I am looking for.  I got done functioning but not sure how to get NEXT to pass through a prototype cell.  Since the NEXT / DONE button will be UIBarButton and not a returnKeyType.  Also tagging will not work since it is a prototype and not individual textFields

Comment: Look at this Git once : https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding are you looking for similar function?

Comment: Dev_Tandel thank you for the link.  I am using Swift 3.0 and don't plan on bridging any Objec C into my code.  Also I am looking to place a ToolBar on top of a number pad that has a next button and then turns into done when you are on the last field.  I appreciate your help though.